# Why /*@ isn't a comment in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comments

This script http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js looks like a big comment, but it works. Why /*@ doesn't behave like a comment?

Comment: More on SO related to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843247/cc-on-and-ie6-detection)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This uses a proprietry Microsoft feature called [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/121hztk3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). As far as non-Microsoft browsers are concerned, it is a comment (but they don't need the shiv).

Comment: But if this `/*@` is only for IE, why this script is included in html with another condition: `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->`. What this double-check is needed for?

Comment: I can only guess at the author's motivation, but conditional comments stop other browsers trying to download it, while conditional compilation stops it being executed if you roll it up into your standard single minified JS package.

Answer (score 5):

Here some more [info](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/conditionalcompile.shtml) and the [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/121hztk3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

It is a comment - multiline comment. All browsers suports comments ( // or /*  ... */ ) in JavaScript. But only IE checks for the @ in the comment and recognize the part of the script for the conditional compilation. This is for usage of the non-standart Microsoft features.

There is also conditional comments[<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in HTML, which will be removed in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack  that uses IE's strange way of not considering `/*@` a comment.