# What is the meaning of `/*@`?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why /*@ isn't a comment in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596109/why-isnt-a-comment-in-javascript)

In the HTML5Shiv script the entire file appears to be commented out, but wrapped with an `@` ("at" sign, "ampersat" etc) prior to the `*/`.

Snippet: `/*@cc_on(function....this, document)@*/`

I haven't come across this before and couldn't find any references to how this works on the HTML5Shiv sites or after searching Google/StackOverfow, but have a feeling it's somehow to trick the browser to only work in IE?

Does anybody know why it's coded this way?

http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: `@` is not an ampersat[sic]. `&` is an ampersand.

Comment: @Neal: Lol, "to make a point of some sort" :D

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: `ampersat` is sometimes used as a neologism for `@`. See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24697/does-the-symbol-have-a-name/) on EL&U

Answer (score 0):

It's an IE-specific feature: [Conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Conditional_comments_in_JScript). It marks blocks of code that should only be executed in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It's called conditional compilation and is a "feature" of older IE browsers. You can read up more on [the Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment)