# Detect User's Browser

Tags: javascript, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine what Browser being used, using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505966/determine-what-browser-being-used-using-javascript)

I'm trying to implement a method in JavaScript which would detect the User's browser for starters and print it.

I already know about the Navigator Object in JavaScript, but I do not want to use that. Is there any other way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use that? It has everything inside? Do you want to detect the browsers by the behavior?

Comment: There is but this is not a good idea - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505966/determine-what-browser-being-used-using-javascript/10507780#10507780

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Browser_Detection_and_Cross_Browser_Support

Comment: +1 because this one came up before duplicate on google!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the navigator property you are out of luck because this is the only way to detect the user agent in javascript.

Comment: Well it's hardly the only way... One could write a library to test for browser specific traits, but the navigator property is the only easy and reliable way

Comment: Opera and Chrome have an object for that "purpose". It is awkward, but it is there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) (which indirectly uses the navigator object I guess, but you don't have to touch it)

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { color:green; font-weight:bolder; margin:3px 0 0 10px; }
  div { color:blue; margin-left:20px; font-size:14px; }
  span { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Browser info:</p>

<script>
    jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {
      $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>")
                .appendTo( document.body );
    });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Browser info:
webkit : true
version : 536.10
safari : true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `$.browser` [1] functionality.

Or something like CSS Browser Selector [2] to add CSS classes to the `<html>` element

[1] http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

[2] http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Answer (score 0):

if you don/t want to use Navigator then user jquery Here is detaied about it.

[jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can directly test for the method(s) that you need to use. For example, while current versions of all the browsers support the `window.addEventListener` method, you may want to detect whether that method exists and if not attempt some other way to listen to the event that you want.